# How to get current page of django rest pagination in List Api View?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How am I, with this code, supposed to get the current page of pagination in Django Rest in a proper way?

```
class LatestEpisodesAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = LatestEpisodeSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(LatestEpisodesAPIView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.render()
        cache.set("apiepisode_p_" + HOWTOGETCURRENTPAGINATIONPAGE, res, 60*5)

        return res
```

In this code I wanted to cache the response of the current page for 5 minutes, by which extravagant joining costs could be averted as the cpu operation costs could peak a high of 500ms per request, and this endpoint is frequently used. To that end, the prerequisite is a unique key for each page, which, in common sense, would be the page number. However, inasmuch the impoverished lackluster inherent nature of DRF's official documentation, information about pagination per se is already scarcer than hen's teeth, let alone trying to get the current page. After hours of scouring the length and breadth of DRF docs, and brute-forcing google search, I myself still fail to find any way to accomplish this goal.
I believe I could do this by `request.query_params.get("page")` but this seems really hard-coded and looks more like a hack than a proper way of doing things.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no "proper" way to accomplish this goal in Django REST. So I've come up with this "hack", still more "proper" than the one in the question:
`request.query_params.get(StandardResultsSetPagination.page_size_query_param)`

Thanks a lot!